# How would you synthesize this kind of bass?

Tags: sound-design, bass

I like to recreate sounds from tunes I listen to, especially if they have something unique about them, to get a better understanding of synthesis and the possibilities I might have missed.

But the bass(es?) in this track have defeated me.

(Please listen to at least half the track to hear the different ways the same(?) bass is used)

I think I can hear an envelope release on the pitch, causing it to go so low you can hear individual clicks and this means there is probably a HPF set to cut off the rumbling lows. But that 'release on pitch' sound could also be glide.

I can also hear the (typical for a bass sound) env decay on LPF filter cutoff but the overall texture definitely sounds BPF to my ears. I suppose this could also be an HPF/LPF combo.

So far I'm using PWM with duty cycle close to 0% to produce the clickiness whilst avoiding too much low frequency content but I could be wrong.

There's also a chorus involved I believe because the sound seems very 'wide' for a bass sound and that which seems tied to the tempo. And of course a LOT of compression.

Of course I'm going to keep trying but could I use your ears to work out the architecture and layering of this sound?

Do you think it came from a mono of poly synth for a start?

**EDIT:** After some further experimentation, I believe the mode is mono, with legato glide.

(I noticed that the link to the video sometimes starts you at the start of the album. The track in question starts at 39:04)